# C# - Visual Studio suggesting I rename a property to something else that already exists

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Here is the code:

```
namespace Phylor.Application.FrontEnd.Search.Models.Adjudication
{
    public class ResultsGridViewModel
    {
        public List<ResultGridProductModel> NmResult = new List<ResultGridProductModel>();
        public List<ResultGridProductModel> WlsResult = new List<ResultGridProductModel>();
        public List<ResultGridPepModel> PepResult = new List<ResultGridPepModel>();
        public List<ResultGridProductModel> MedResult = new List<ResultGridProductModel>();
    }

    public class ResultGridProductModel
    {
        public long ResultId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Identifier { get; set; }
        public string IndividualName { get; set; }
        public string EntityName { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string PlaceOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Score { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Race { get; set; }
        public string Nationality { get; set; }
        public string EyeColor { get; set; }
        public string Height { get; set; }
        public string Weight { get; set; }
        public string HairColor { get; set; }
        public string SourceRegion { get; set; }
        public string Program { get; set; }
        public string AliasList { get; set; }
        public string Caution { get; set; }
        public string SourceAgencyName { get; set; }
        public string SourceAgencyAcronym { get; set; }
        public string SourceParentAgency { get; set; }
        public string SourceCountry { get; set; }
        public string ServiceName { get; set; }
        public bool IsMatch { get; set; }
    }
```

Now see the screengrab to see what I see in Visual Studio, particularly SourceCountry.

[image: ResultsClass]

I've never seen this broken-dotted border before, and Google is not helping me understand what it is.  What does this border mean, and why is it suggesting I rename Caution to it?

Comment: You probably edited it by mistake, and then corrected.

Comment: Did you copy paste the `Caution` property to make this new `SourceCountry` line by any chance? Visual Studio is trying to be clever and suggest you need to refactor other code to match the new name.

Comment: The rename suggestion occurs when you renamed a variable, so you can just ignore it if you don't need to rename it.

Comment: Try to build your code and see if it goes away. Also search for word caution in your solution and see if you find anything? You might have copied caution property to this line.

Comment: @DavidG you nailed it.  That's exactly what I did!  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

That’s just a suggestion and the broken dotted border is only a highlight of the text selected for the current action.

You could just ignore it tho, if you don’t want to rename, besides as we all know, it’s only a suggestion.

Comment: Hi Nicholas - welcome to Stack Overflow! Actually your statement of "the broken dotted border is only a highlight of the text selected for the current action" is not true.  That pesky little border is there and will not go away no matter where you click in the solution.